# How to downgrade application with WIX Bundle?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, windows-installer, burn

I created a WIX Burn setup.
The Bundle chained multiple .MSI files for global installation (all MSI support  downgrading).

```
<Bundle Name="APP 4.3.0" 
    Version="4.3.0" 
    Manufacturer="Manu" 
    UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">

<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="VCppRedistPackage"/>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="DotNet4Package"/>

  <MsiPackage Id="CrystalReportPackage"
              SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)_CommonFiles\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_9.msi"
              DownloadUrl="http://MyAppRuntime/CrystalReport_NET40/CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_9.msi"
              InstallCondition="NOT CR32VersionInstalled OR IsInstalledCRVersionOlder"
              Compressed="no"
              Permanent="yes"
              DisplayInternalUI="no" 
              Visible="yes" />

  <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)..\OthersSetup\Setup.msi" Permanent="yes" DisplayInternalUI="no" Visible="yes" />

  <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.AppInstall.TargetDir)AppInstall.msi" Permanent="no" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Visible="no" />
</Chain>
```

I really have to allow downgrading for testing reasons.
Any solution or proposal ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What solution did you end up going with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burn does not allow downgrade for MSI packages. When a newer package is already installed, Burn proceeds to mark the package as applicable and the install then fails since the MSI blocks the downgrade unless `SuppressDowngradeFailure` is set to "yes".

See [WixStandardBootstrapperApplication Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/bal/wixstandardbootstrapperapplication.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Huemac! Finally we found another way to solve the problem, I will explain it later in this post.