# Bootstrapper ignoring downgrade instead of failing

Tags: wix, burn

We have four Packages and a number of Bundles which install different combinations of these Packages.

The MsiPackage element for these Packages in the Bundle definition all have the Vital attribute set to "yes".

We found a scenario where we think the Bootstrapper should fail but doesn't.

Package A is installed in version 2.

The user runs a Bootstrapper that includes Package A version 1.

Instead of failing, the Bootstrapper ignores the downgrade:

```
[0DC8:06B4][2016-03-24T14:29:36]i201: Planned package: vcredist_x64.exe, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: None
[0DC8:06B4][2016-03-24T14:29:36]i201: Planned package: msxml6_x64.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[0DC8:06B4][2016-03-24T14:29:36]i201: Planned package: prodist.sts.vault.msi, state: Obsolete, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0DC8:06B4][2016-03-24T14:29:36]i201: Planned package: prodist.sts.line.msi, state: Obsolete, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0DC8:06B4][2016-03-24T14:29:36]i201: Planned package: prodist.sts.server.msi, state: Obsolete, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0DC8:06B4][2016-03-24T14:29:36]i201: Planned package: prodist.sts.client.msi, state: Obsolete, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0DC8:06B4][2016-03-24T14:29:36]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
```

What are we missing? How can I cause the standard bootstrapper to fail in this case?

Comment: Burn does not allow downgrade for MSI packages. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27523543/600559

Comment: Yes. So, why is the bootstrapper process concluding with success instead of failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error because Burn follows Windows versioning rules: Newer versions are better than older. So it's not a failure if newer versions are already installed; it just means Burn can safely skip the older versions that the bundle is carrying.

If you want to block such bundle install attempts, use [`ProductSearch`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/productsearch.html) to find the versions of installed packages.

Comment: I understand there are various means to detect packages already present. But how can I cause the install to fail based on conditions?

Comment: Do I need a custom bootstrap application?

Comment: Use Condition: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/bal/condition.html